# Linear algebra to solve equation for a circle

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck with how to solve this equation:
$$ax^2 + ay^2 + bx + cy + d = 0$$ given three points, $(-2,7), (-4,5)$, and $(4,-3)$.

My steps: 1. Set up three equations,
$$53a-2b+7c+d=0 \\
41a-4b+5c+d=0 \\
25a+4b-3c+d=0$$
2. Created augmented matrix and used my calculator to get rref form (this is what we've been studying and manual row reduction is painful). I get an answer in rref form. Are these the equations for $a, b, c, d$? The answer would be
$$a=x+1/29 \\
b=y-2/29 \\
c=x-4/29 \\
d=d.$$

I don't need the actual answer just confirmation that I'm using the right process, or to be told no and pointed in the right process.

Comment: Your initial approach in step $1$ looks fine, but following that, there shouldn't be any $x$ or $y$ in your solution. Where did those come from?

Comment: The RREF returned for example 1,0,0,1/29,0 for row 1. I guess I'm confused about what those numbers represent, and how to translate the answer into answers for a,b,c,d.

Comment: The RREF operation takes the matrix representing your system of three equations and gives you a new matrix representing an equivalent system of equations. So you should read the result rows back in the same form you wrote them, e.g. $1a+0b+0c+1/29d=0$.

Comment: Karl's comment here shows that $a = (-1/29)d$, and the other rows will similarly be multiples of $d$. This gives you an infinite family of solutions, i.e., you can choose $d$ to be just about anything, and the other constants will scale accordingly. This ties into @John's answer below ("you can choose $a$ to be whatever you like").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a circle then $a$ cannot be zero, and you can divide through by it:

$$x^2 + y^2 + b'x + c'y + d' = 0$$

where the primes are the variables divided by $a$.

Then you have three equations with three unknowns. You can choose $a$ to be whatever you like.

Does this help?

Comment: The problem asks me to solve for a,b,c,d, so I am not sure what you mean by 'a can be whatever I like.' Also, you haven't eliminated a, I still have 1/a x b, c, and d. Sorry, I'm at the beginning of a Covid/independent class and might not be explaining this as well as I'd like.

Comment: You can multiply your original equation by any non-zero constant you like, and it will still be the same circle, so one of $a,b,c,d$ is arbitrary. Come to think of it, it's even easier to simply choose $a$ to be $1$.